# Use shinyalert to confirm data update

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I would like to make the data behind my shiny refreshable upon user's request. However, as the refresh takes several minutes, I would like to warn the user before actually starting the process and allow them to cancel.

I use the super `shinyalert` package by @deanattali to setup the alert. Here is a small reproducible example. Think of `data(mtcars)` as fetching some data, and the average calculation as some data processing, both of which takes some time.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(data.table)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    useShinyalert(),
    actionButton("refresh", "Refresh"),
    dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
        shinyalert("You are abouto to refresh data...", showCancelButton = TRUE)
    })

    aggregated_data <- eventReactive(input$shinyalert, {
        message("reload data")
        data(mtcars)
        as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(avg_speed = mean(mpg)), by = cyl]
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    output$table <- renderDataTable(
        aggregated_data()
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, it does not work as I want. It reloads the data whenever `input$shinyalert` changes, not when the user clicked "OK" (I know this is the expected functionality, I just don't know how to achieve the functionality I want). How can I rewrite this to recalculate `aggregated_data` reactive only if the input$shinyalert changed to `TRUE`?

(I tried a simple if statement within the `eventReactive` but it does not return anything if the condition evaluates to `FALSE`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `eventReactive` the wrong way. This isn't working as expected because `shinyalert` returns `FALSE` if you click `cancel` and thus, triggers `eventReactive` - see [shinyalert github readme](https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert#modal-return-value)

> When there is no input field in the modal, the value of the modal is TRUE if the user clicked the “OK” button, and FALSE if the user clicked the “Cancel” button.

Try `reactiveValues` instead of `eventReactive` and use `req()`inside the observer which ignores `FALSE` values

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    shinyalert("You are abouto to refresh data...", showCancelButton = TRUE)
  })

  aggregated <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    req(input$shinyalert)
    message("reload data")
    data(mtcars)
    aggregated$data <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, .(avg_speed = mean(mpg)), by = cyl]
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    aggregated$data
  )
}
```

Also, if you like to set up the `ignoreNULL = FALSE` again, you can specify this with the creation of `aggregated`